# When is $A = k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/I$ integrally closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that it is not easy to determine that $A$ is a UFD (or that it is a local, noetherian dimension 1 domain with principal maximal ideal).

Can someone suggest strategies for showing that a finitely generated $k$-algebra is integrally closed (or not?)

I know that integral closure is a local property.

(Context: I am learning some algebraic geometry, and I need to deal with questions involving the normality of some variety. Some of the cases I can deal with using the commutative algebra that I know, but othertimes I wonder if there is some theorem that I am not aware of. I don't want to give the specific rings that I am stuck on because I would like to solve them on my own.)

Edit: $k$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: Do you know what $I$ looks like?

Comment: If for example $A$ is smooth then it is integrally closed.

Comment: Normality is equivalent to regularity in codimension 1. So it's equivalent to check that the local rings at codimension 1 primes are all regular i.e. principal. This can be a hard thing to do in  complete generality. It might be more helpful if you have a specific example in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is what you had in mind, but basically there are algorithms to determine normality for a given such $I$ -- see e.g. algorithm 3.6.12 of "A Singular Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by G.M. Greuel and G. Pfister, where the non-norml locus is calculated. In short: Compute $r:=\dim (A)$, let $J$ be the ideal of the $n-r$ minors of the Jacobian of $I$, choose $0\neq a\in J':=\sqrt{I+J}$, then $(\langle a\rangle :(aJ':J'))$ is an ideal defining the non-normal locus of $V(I)$.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer: Please, can you give a reference to your claim: "If $A$ is smooth then it is integrally closed". Thanks.

Comment: @user237522 See this mathoverflow answer for example: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20047/what-is-the-relationship-between-being-normal-and-being-regular